# Getting Closest TR with jQuery when clicking on an "OnClick" function inside a TD?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is this possible? Is the fact I am using an inline onclick function deterring from getting the TR row?

My Table Row looks like this:

```
<tr role="row" class="odd"><td><a class="masterskutd" id="mastersku_FL538-J"
      onclick="editMasterSKU('FL538-J');return false;">FL538-J</a></tr>
```

In an external JS file `functions.js` I am trying things such as this

```
function editMasterSKU(SKU) {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    $(tr).addClass('clicked');
    // var tr = $(this).parents('tr');
    console.log(tr);
```

Nothing I do seems to catch the TR that the function was clicked upon, the `console.log` only brings back `w.fn.init(0)` (not entirely sure what this means) with a length of 0, and it is not adding the class to the row.

How can I get the TR in a jQuery variable when clicking on my onclick function inside the `td` / `a`?

Comment: `onclick` functions have no explicit `this`. Why not use jQuery event listener also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because functions called from inline event attributes do not run under the scope of the element which raised the event. They instead run under the scope of the `window`, hence `this` is not what you expect it to be.

To fix this you can pass `this` as an argument to the function from the `onclick`:

```js
function editMasterSKU(a, SKU) {
  var tr = $(a).closest('tr');
  $(tr).addClass('clicked');
}
```

```css
.clicked {
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td>
      <a class="masterskutd" id="mastersku_FL538-J" onclick="editMasterSKU(this, 'FL538-J');return false;">FL538-J</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However it's worth noting that you should not be using inline event attributes at all. Use unobtrusive event handlers instead. As you're already including jQuery in the page it can be done like this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.masterskutd').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    $tr.addClass('clicked');
    console.log($(this).data('sku'));
  });
})
```

```css
.clicked a {
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td>
      <a class="masterskutd" id="mastersku_FL538-J" data-SKU="FL538-J" href="#">FL538-J</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note the use of the `data` attribute to store the custom meta data in the element itself, and also the addition of the `href` attribute, which is required for the HTML to be valid.

Comment: Don't think I could've asked for a better answer -- tested both, they work as shown, very thorough, good lesson!